# ¿Se puede utilizar Bootstrap 4 y Angular Material Design 2 en un mismo proyecto Angular 4.?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Mi pregunta consiste en que si en un mismo proyecto `Angular 4` se puede utilizar `Bootstrap 4` junto con `Angular Material Design 2` sin que esto provoque algun mal funcionamiento de cualquiera de los 2 framework. Pues `bootstrap` tiene muchas utilidades que nos facilita el trabajo `css` (`Grid, alineacion, ...` ) y `Angular Material Design` nos brinda varios `componentes` facil de integrar con `angular`.

Answer (score 0):

Despues de mucho googlear encontre [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772811/angular-material-2-with-bootstrap-4-grid) y [este otro enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497542/can-bootstrap-4-be-integrated-along-with-angular-material-2/45498121#45498121) donde se platea que se puede utilizar los dos framework juntos principalmente el sistema de grid.